# Unable to Decide which Amazon Web service goes well for our business?

Tags: web-services, web, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, rds

**Our Business Needs:**

1. Want to launch a java based Web service
2. Need a mySQL database for the web application
3. We will need to run same web service securely for 10 different cuatomers

**Our Plan:**

1. Will go for EC2 service
2. We will use some application stacks having java / database and web server

Questions:

1. For the above services do we need all the three services EC2 / RDS and S3?
2. Can we prepare our Linux image with all the needs and upload it and tun it on S3?

Please help us with your valuable answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're question is a little vague. You could do this all on 1 EC2 instance, depending on the load. You can install Java, and MySQL on a single linux instance. Weather this will work for you or not, depends on the app. load, the size of ec2 instance you use. Many things.

As for creating your own linux image, yes you can do this, there are many articles on the web detailing this, a quick google search turned up this one http://computeretal.blogspot.com/2010/05/create-amazon-machine-image-from.html

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

For the above 3 requirements, you can do this with just EC2 for the linux instances with Java web servers (Tomcat etc) and RDS for the MySQL (both of which are part of the free trial now).

You would only need S2 if you needed file storage.

You cannot premake the instances offline, you need to make them live.